# in Makefile, I don't know why this += operator doesn't work

Tags: makefile

I have a test Makefile

```
CPPFLAGS += "option B"
$(info CPPFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS))
```

when I do `make`, I get

```
CPPFLAGS = "option B"
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

but when I do `make CPPFLAGS="options A"`, I get

```
CPPFLAGS = option A
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I wanted the string "option B" to be appended to "option A" coming from the command line.
What is wrong with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because variables from the command-line take precedence over the rest. From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive):

> If a variable has been set with a command argument,
>   then **ordinary assignments** in the makefile **are ignored**. If
>   you want to set the variable in the makefile even though it was set
>   with a command argument, you can use an `override` directive, which is a
>   line that looks like this:
>
> ```
>  override variable = value
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>  override variable := value
> ```
>
> To append more text to a variable defined on the command line, use:
>
> ```
>  override variable += more text
> ```
>
> Variable assignments marked with the `override` flag **have a higher
>   priority** than all other assignments, except another override.
>   Subsequent assignments or appends to this variable which are not
>   marked `override` will be ignored.

Try this:

```
override CPPFLAGS += option B
```